# Why does my CPU stops after Windows getting boot windows 10?

Tags: windows, bios, shutdown, desktop-computer

I have Intel Pentium Core2Duo with 4GB RAM, no dedicated GPU, PSU:240W.

Whenever I boot my PC, Windows closes after few seconds with some sound and then CPU fan stops and PSU also. But here is the curveball: Whenever I boot into BIOS it works. I tried many suggestions, I removed the CPU fan, cleaned the dust and put it back on but I still face the problem. HDD also checked and it's working fine in other computers. Another thing is that the monitor when VGA is plugged it looks blurry, I mean low quality. Please help.

Comment: That sounds very much like hardware issues. The core 2 duo was discontinued in 2012 so its very old hardware. The simple answer is to get new hardware.

Comment: Or test another operating system, e.g. running Linux from a USB flash drive. If that works, then either the OS on the HDD, or the HDD itself is at fault. See https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview , for example, to make a Live Ubuntu USB drive. BTW, if Linux works, and Windows doesn't, consider migration.

Comment: ok i will try which linux should i try?

Comment: Previously i did ubuntu it got stuck and gave an error in booting(during setup)

Comment: I am thinking of applying thermal paste becuz proccessor got very hot after one boot

Comment: There's only so much effort worth applying to something that old, really.

Answer (score 2):

It was due to a faulty 2GB DDR2 RAM.

I replaced it and now it works completely fine.